# How to implement erasing feature in a Paint-like application?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-bitmap

I have a custom view DrawingPanel and in I'm using this to make a paint application which lets you draw on image.I now want to add the erasing capability to make the image transparent.I've tried using  `mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));`    but it gives me black color on touch and I can't change this color.How to improve the erasing bitmap functionality?

```
public DrawingPanel(Context context, int color) {
                super(context);
                this.color = color;
                setFocusable(true);
                setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                this.setOnTouchListener(this);

                mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
                mPaint = new Paint();
                mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mPaint.setDither(true);
                mPaint.setColor(color);
                mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
                mPaint.setTextSize(30);

                mPath = new Path();
                paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color, false));
                mCanvas = new Canvas();
            }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            for (PathPoints p : paths) {
                mPaint.setColor(p.getColor());
                Log.v("", "Color code : " + p.getColor());
                if (p.isTextToDraw()) {
                    canvas.drawText(p.textToDraw, p.x, p.y, mPaint);
                } else {
                    canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), mPaint);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you really want transparency in the image, or do you just want to erase it to the background color?

Comment: @MikeM. I want it to erase to background color but still have the bitmap (having transparent parts) which can be saved later.

Comment: Just set the color of your Paint when erasing to the color of the background, or, use two different View layers so the Portduff XFer mode works correctly

Comment: @Guardanis Could you provide some code for using two different view layers?

Comment: Depends how you're doing it. Either way, you want a <RelativeLayout><View android:background="your_color"><DrawingPanel></RelativeLayout> with both children having equal width/height and layout_centerInParent="true" attributes.